# Can you open a tarball on Mac OS X in the GUI?

Tags: macos, gui, archiving, tar

If I send a tar.gz file to a Mac OS X user, will they be able to open it in the GUI, just like a zip file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, handled by the same application (Archive Utility.app)